# Error every second in Apache error log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I'm getting this error every second in my apache error log, what is causing this, how to fix?

[debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are have debugging enabled. Check the log level.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#errorlog

Comment: so it's nothing wrong, i should just change the loglevel?